# Bitbucket Build Status Notifier - Cannot Extract Access Token

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am trying to setup a build status notifications that will publish in our Bitbucket cloud and I will be using the "Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin" which is already installed on our Jenkins. Also, I have already added a consumer with read/write permission on repositories. However, everytime I use the credential that I created from jenkins which the the Username/Password = Key/Secrets of consumer, I get this error below:

> class org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthExceptionCannot extract an acces token. Response was: {"error_description": "Cannot use client_credentials with a consumer marked as "public". Calls for auto generated consumers should use urn:bitbucket:oauth2:jwt instead.", "error": "invalid_grant"}

I am following these plugin setup instructions - https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-build-status-notifier/

Answer (score 14):

Change status of consumer to private.
[image]